# Cannot disable Lenovo Flex 3 touchpad

Tags: windows-8, drivers, touchpad

I have a Lenovo Flex 3 running Windows 8.1, and I can't find a way to make my touchpad stay off. The hotkey to turn it off at F6 does work, my trackpad will stop working for a time only to randomly turn on by itself or when I restart the computer.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the touchpad driver, which didn't help. And, when I go into mouse settings in the control panel and go to 'change settings' when I select 'Lenovo pointing device' the option to disable the touchpad is grayed out. My account is administrator, so I have no clue why I can't click the disable button. Even Lenovo support couldn't fix this, I will be forever grateful if you can help me! I'm at the end of my rope here.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of my problem http://i.imgur.com/UpDSz0j.jpg

Comment: "Plugged into PS/2 mouse port" doesn't sound like a touchpad.

Comment: It is odd that it says that, but the other two items listed in the hardware tab are related to my Logitech mouse. Alps Electric is the manufacturer of my touchpad also. Any idea if that's part of the problem?

Comment: Perhaps Lenovo will have a suggestion if nothing turns up here.

Comment: I wish that was the case, I've been on the phone with Lenovo technical support about this 3 times to no avail. Oh well, maybe I should just learn to live with it. Thanks though.

Comment: I hope you know the "escalating" trick.  There are usually about three levels of technical support, and the higher levels are usually savvier than the low levels.

Comment: Huh, can't say I do, but I'll give that a try in hopes of getting to the people who know the system of my particular laptop. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you tell the person who answers that you've already called and they weren't able to help you, so therefore would they please escalate your call.

Comment: I'll remember that, it's always helpful to know the right things to say to get what you need. Haha and thanks again for being the only one to reply. ;)

Comment: I have a Dell running Windows 7, so maybe apples and oranges, but I was able to disable my touchpad permanently by typing (Win)+(X) to bring up the Windows Mobility Center, and then using the Touchpad control.  I've been told that this is just a somewhat user-friendlier front-end to functionality that exists in either Control Panel or Device Manager.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i fixed it myself... Just go to control panel > Mouse > Hardware > Select PS/2 Compatible mouse >properties> driver tab > click on uninstall > restart your pc

Note : disconnect any external mouse before doing this